# png transparency as a background header

Tags: background-image

I have a top nav header bar I want to have about 40% opacity...

I was looking at other threads comparing .PNG vs css Opacity... from what I read, the .png might perform better...

so my question is...

for a top nav header: width:100%, height:50px;

Would it be better to use a 1x1 pixel transparent image, or something more like a 1x50 transparent image?

do thousands of 1x1 images load faster then several hundred 1x50 images?

nit picky i know...

thx

Answer (score 0):

One single image will load much faster than many hundred larger images, but then you're going to waste an awwful lot of cpu time tiling/stretching that one single pixel.

What are you trying to achieve with the background? A gradient?